# Magento 2 equivelent of __("whatever %s", $variable)

Tags: magento2

In Magento 1 you can use something like this

`Mage::helper('module')->__('Hi %s, there is an error', $name);`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21726921/10121426

Does Magento 2 support this?  If so what is the syntax?

Tried `__('Hi %s, there is an error', $name)` but doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**__('Hi %1, there is an error', $name)**

if you want more you have to add digit like below

**__('Hi %1 %2, there is an error', $name,$lastName)**

Comment: Spot on! brilliant. Worth asking the community!